# Run a script on an external file in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, sparql, rdf, webstorm

I'm trying to run some JavaScript on an RDF-XML file on my local machine on WebStorm. I want to replicate the functionality of writing JavaScript into Firebug *after* the document loads - something not explicitly included in the HTML code itself (RDF-XML in my case), kinda like in JSFiddle.

The idea is to test some JS code on the RDF document without having to do it on a browser debugger like Firebug (not the best place to write code, and I dont want to keep copy pasting back and forth from an editor/IDE).

I am a JS and WebStorm newbie. Im not sure if WebStorm allows me to do this, and if so, how I configure it to do so.

Could anyone help? How do you guys debug write and debug bulky JavaScript?

Comment: do you need to quickly evaluate your js code without creating html page/loading it in browser? You can easily evaluate your code using Node.js run configuration - every .js file has a 'run' in its right-click menu, choosing this action allows running code with Node.js. Also, JavaScript Debugger console is 'live' - you can evaluate expressions there while debugging

Comment: I dont think this solves my problem though. I need the JS to run "on" a document that can't <include/src/ref> it.

Comment: haven't got what you mean, sorry... When the certain page is loaded while debugging, you can write javascript in debugger cponsole to evaluate it - without including/referencing it from your document

Comment: Awesome. And what if I wish to do the same thing in "compiled" mode? The console is  good for interpreted JS, which I could achieve in the browser as well.